# How to move/rotate an object in OpenGL according to it's local position / rotation

Tags: python, c++, opengl

Getting into C++ and OpenGL, coming from a Python background, where you have *applyMovement* & *applyRotation* (and of course, *worldPosition*, *worldOrientation*) I feel like I'm missing something with OpenGL. Basically, I have a player, a cube.

I want the cube to move back/forth with the up/down arrow keys, always in the position **it's facing**. Then, with left / right arrows, I want the player to rotate around it's **own** origin. So I will end up with an old Resident Evil style of control scheme (Tank Controls)

Now, **glTranspose** and **glRotate** work, but depending on whichever I do **first**, it seems to move in the correct direction, but rotate around world origin.

OR

It rotates around it's own axis, but the movement is always according to world Axis.

I'm not looking to move/rotate the world or world+camera, as I'm looking to do a 3rd Person fixed camera game. Basically I'm looking to do the exact same as what *applyMovement*/*applyRotation* in Python do. But I'm open to ideas in terms of how this could be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using immediate mode for rendering, you first need to glTranslate the negative vector of the object's center, apply the rotation, and then glTranslate back to its position. Effectively:

```
glTranslate( -center.x, -center.y, -center.z );
glRotate( ... );
glTranslate( center.x, center.y, center.z );
```

Now this is only for the rendering part. For the movement, you will need to keep track of the angles that the cube is being rotated by and use sine and cosine to move it forward or backward.